# Why would you render JSON at the end of an API controller that's only used for endpoints?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say you hit the `create` action in a `Foos` controller, what would be the purpose of rendering json? at the end of the action? Is this what is passed back to the post request upon success?

```
  render json: foo, serializer: FooSerializer, status: :created
```

Comment: I think that the answer to your last question is "yes."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common practice. So the consumer of that endpoint can use the newly created resource without making an extra request (e.g. extra GET somewhere to get data on that newly created resource).

With POST, a return body is expected when the code is `201`. Usually this response body is the entity representation for that newly created resource. If you didn't want to return anything, you could use `204` `:no_content`. The `201` is nice as an acknowledgement that something was created. `200` is acceptable as well.

You can return anything you want like `{ message: 'created' }`. Just be consistent and have all your endpoints do the same or don't over think it and just return that newly created `foo`.